# How to show two images each taking 50% of screen width using ionic?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to show two circular images in a row such that both images take 50% of the screen width. Also, I want to make sure that the aspect ratio of the images is maintained if they are scaled up or down. Here's the code that I have used:

```
<ion-view>
  <div class="row" >

    <div class="col col-50">
        <img src="img/Screen-Language/spanish.png" >
    </div>

    <div class="col col-50">
        <img src="img/Screen-Language/english.png" >
    </div>

   </div>
</ion-view>
```

This code leads to overlapping to two images and each image take more than 50% of screen width. How can I fix this issue. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the css for `col`, `col-50` and `row`. That way we can see where/how you're setting this `50% of screen`. but from here it sounds like a padding/margin issue

Comment: CSS for this is defined in the ionic framework. Please go over this link for reference: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-explicit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this

```
<ion-view>
  <div class="row" >

    <div class="col col-50">
        <img src="img/Screen-Language/spanish.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="col col-50">
        <img src="img/Screen-Language/english.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>

   </div>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Adding the style="width:100%" fixed the issue. Thanks Ladislav for the help.

Comment: Is not needed to add `style="width:100%"` to images, class `full-image` do just that

Answer (score 0):

you also can do it this way (css way):

```
img{
    width: 45.7vw;
    height: 100px; //some custom height
    margin: 2px;
}
```